# make JavaFX wait until Timeline finishes

Tags: javafx, timeline

I have two timeline which runs inside one function, they are both affect one object, problem is when I play first timeline, other timeline also starts within next line of code, how can I wait until fist timeline finish then play another timeline?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Timeline.play()` is asynchronous—it starts the animation in the background and returns immediately. There are several ways to achieve sequential execution. Which fits best depends on your use case.

1. Use just one `Timeline` and move the `KeyFrame`s from your second timeline to the first one, with adjusted start duration.
2. Start the second timeline when the first one is finished: `timeline1.setOnFinished(e -> timeline2.play())`.
3. If you can, use `Transition`s instead of `Timeline`s and wrap them in a `SequentialTransition`.